# Diagram with arranged countries polygons

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shapefile, tmap

I am looking for solution of a special diagram using following data set (below). The diagram has to contain the polygons of the countries from the data set, but they have to be (1) placed next to each other, not by long,lat coordinates; (2) the size of the polygon of the each country has to correspond to the relative size, which is a t$rs variable (calculated as it's shown below); (3) the fill color of each country depends on the value of t$value variable -- if it's positive the color is green and red if negative.

My code so far is:

```
 library(ggmap)
 library(dplyr)
 library(sf) 
 library(tidyverse)
 library(gridExtra)
 library(rgdal)
 library(tmap)

 # The data set
 t <- data.frame(id    = c(136,142,172,567),
            name  = c("Italy","Norway","Finland","Singapore"),
            value = c(-0.921253632,245.6713064,4.049413648,207.5896534))

 # Min value in absolute terms
 min = min(abs(t$value))

 # Relative value w.r.t. min value 
 t$rs <- t$value / min

 # Shape files for countries
 # https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/esri::world-countries-generalized/about

 # Unzip files from the ArcGIS archive file
 unzip("World_Countries_(Generalized).zip", exdir = ".")
 shp.file <- "World_Countries__Generalized_.shx"
 countries <- readOGR(shp.file)

 qtm(countries[countries$COUNTRY %in% t$name,])
```

[image]My output diagram is attached. It's a bit far from desired shape.

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted your data import slightly using `st_read()` from the `sf` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

# Unzip files from the ArcGIS archive file
unzip("World_Countries_(Generalized).zip", exdir = ".")
shp.file <- "World_Countries__Generalized_.shx"
countries <- st_read(shp.file) 
   
countries %>% 
   left_join(t, by = c("COUNTRY" = "name")) %>% 
   filter(!is.na(id)) %>% 
   st_as_sf() %>% 
   tm_shape() + 
   tm_fill("value") +
   tm_facets(by = "COUNTRY")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This advances me quite a lot. Is there a way to plot these polygons of the countries with different sizes? The relative size to be used for that is stored in the variable `t$rs`.

Comment: Based on the available [settings](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/3.3-2/topics/tm_facets) it's not possible to scale the individual polygons by a custom value. What's the intention behind this step?

Comment: @mgrund I agree with you. I've faced the same problem before and I could never find a solution to scale each facet independently. I guess it must be possible though...